# Query was Empty error in php using PDO

Tags: php, pdo, phpmyadmin

I am getting an error as follows:
Array ( [0] => 42000 [1] => 1065 [2] => Query was empty )
This, on execution of the following query:

```
$servername = "localhost"; //Define the servername here
$username = "admin";       //Define the username here
$password = "";            //Define the password here
$dbname = "data";          //Define the database name here
$x=0;
$construct = null;        //Defining the database variable for Sector     Selection
$Price_value=null;        //Defining the database variable for Price Range
$type_value = null;         //Defining the database variable for Type of Building

$sql = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername; dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
$sql->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
//Connection to database

foreach($sql->query('SELECT * from data') as $row) {
    print_r($row);
}
echo $dbname;

$dbs = $sql->query('Show databases');                                           //Accessing HTML variable data
$button = (isset($_GET['submit'])?$_GET['submit'] : null);                  
$search = (isset($_GET['search'])?$_GET['search'] : null);
$Type = (isset($_GET['type'])?$_GET['type'] : null);
$Price = (isset($_GET['Price'])?$_GET['Price'] : null);
echo $Type;

if(!$button)
  echo "you didn't submit a keyword";                   //to check whether the submit button was pressed or not
else
{
    echo "you searched for<b>$search</b><hr size = '1'></br>";  
}

$search_exploded = explode(" ", $search);

$construct = "SELECT *FROM data where Sector = $search ";       //Query generation to search according to sector
$sth = $sql->prepare($construct);                               
$sth->bindParam(":search", $search, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$sth->execute();

$sth_type = "SELECT *FROM data where type = $Type  ";       //Query  generated to search according to the Type of Building
$sth_type = $sql->prepare($type_value);
//settype($search, "string");
$sth_type->bindParam(":Type",$Type, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth_type->execute();

$sth_Price = "SELECT *from data where Price = $Price && Sector = $search";          //Query generated to search according to the Price Range
$sth_Price = $sql->prepare($Price_value);
$sth_Price->bindParam(":Price",$Price,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth_Price->execute();


if($sth_type->execute())
    {
        echo "executed";
    }
else{
        echo "not executed";
        $arr = $sth_type->errorInfo();
        print_r($arr);
    }


$foundnum = 0;

//If loops to check the value of input against the database values


if(strcmp($construct, $search))
    {   
        $foundnum+=1;
        $runrows = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        echo "executing";
    }
else if((strcmp($construct,$search))&&(strcmp($Type, $type_value)))
    {   
        $foundnum+=1;
        $runrows = $sth_type->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

else if((strcmp($construct,$search))&&(strcmp($Type, $type_value))&&(strcmp($Price, $Price_value))) 
    {
        $foundnum+=1;
        $runrows = $sth_Price->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
else
    return;

//echo gettype($Price_value);
if($foundnum==0)
echo "Sorry, there are no matching result for '<b>$search</b>'.Try more general words.";
else 
{
 echo "$foundnum results found!<p>";

?>
```

On careful observation, I saw that the query in sth_type and sth_price are not getting executed. Is it so that multiple queries cannot be executed in a single code? My basic aim is to be able to extract the rows from the database that can extract values based on the query based on user input.

Comment: `$sth_type = $sql->prepare($type_value);` Where's `$type_value`. `$sth_Price = $sql->prepare($Price_value);` Where's `$Price_value`? You just set them as null, so no query.

Comment: I changed it to this: $sth_Price = "SELECT *from data where Price = $Price && Sector = $search";  //Query generated to search according to the Price Range
$sth_Price = $sql->prepare($Price_value);
$sth_Price->bindParam(":Price",$Price,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth_Price->execute();
 Error:
Unknown column 'Commercial' in 'where clause

Comment: That's not how you construct a prepared statement. All of your three PDO query sets are wrong. Lets take the first one,`$construct = "SELECT *FROM data where Sector = $search ";` is wrong, it should be `$construct = "SELECT *FROM data where Sector = :search ";`. Then this statement, `$sth->bindParam(":search", $search, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`, look at the third argument, it should be `PDO::PARAM_STR`. Like this way, change the rest of your query sets.Also, look at @JonStirling's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37919253/query-was-empty-error-in-php-using-pdo#comment63289401_37919253).

Comment: Now the query seems to have executed successfully but the value isn't stored in type_value variable.